# Getting integers out of a string containing words in java

Tags: java

Right now I have a string input along the lines of "Stern    Brenda  90  86  45".  I'm trying to find a way to get 90 86 and 45 out of that and assign them as ints to tests 3, 2, and 1 respectively to compute an average of them.

```
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          test3 = line.indexOf(-2, -1);
          test2 = line.indexOf(-5, -4);
          test1 = line.indexOf(-8, -7);
```

This is returning a value of -1 for each test (I tried using a regular expression to start from index -2 and go until another integer is found.  Trying to get a two digit integer (as opposed to if I was just trying to get something like 5 or 6) is really whats throwing me off.  Is using the .indexOf method the best way to go about getting these numbers out of the string?  If so how am I using it incorrectly?

edit: I found a solution that was relatively simple.

```
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          String nums = line.replaceAll("[\\D]", "");
          test1 = Integer.parseInt(nums.substring(0,2));
          test2 = Integer.parseInt(nums.substring(2,4));
          test3 = Integer.parseInt(nums.substring(4,6));
```

For the input "Stern    Brenda  90  86  45", this returns 90 for test1, 86 for test2, and 45 for test3 (all as integers).

Comment: read up on regular expressions

Comment: What do you intend by `line.indexOf(-2, -1)`? You are perhaps meaning to use `line.substring`, but you can't pass that negative arguments: `line.substring(line.length()-2, line.length()-1)` (although the -1 shouldn't be there).

Comment: The regex for a two digit number is `\d\d`

Comment: I tried using one of those in the index of method as well ("[0-9]", -2) (which I think should start at the second to last index and go until it finds a number), however that was not working aswell.

Comment: I might be using the wrong parameters for my intentions.  By using line.indexOf(-2, -1), I'm trying to return a integer starting at the 2nd to last index of the string and ending at the last index of the string (which in my case would give 45).

Answer (score 1):

CheshireMoe almost has it right, but he's accessing a List like an array, which probably won't work.  In his example:

Instead of:

```
  test3 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[tokens.length-1]);
  test2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[tokens.length-2]);
  test1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[tokens.length-3]);
```

Should be:

```
  test3 = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(tokens.size()-1));
  test2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(tokens.size()-2));
  test1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(tokens.size()-3));
```

An easier solution might be just to split the array using the space:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

  String [] tokens = line.split(" ");
  if (tokens.length != 5) {  // catch errors in your data!
     throw new Exception();  // <-- use this if you want to stop on bad data
     // continue;  <-- use this if you just want to skip the record, instead
  }
  test3 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
  test2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
  test1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
}
```

Based on your data, you might also consider putting in some validation like I've shown, to catch things like:

- a value is missing (student didn't take one of the tests)
- not all the grades were entered as numbers (i.e. bad characters)
- first and last name both exist

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to parse the string. This just computes the average.  You can also assign the individual values as you deem appropriate.

```
String s =  "Stern Brenda 90 86 45";
double sum = 0;
```

- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `\\d+` - one or more digits
- `()` - a capture group
- matching on the string `s`

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+)\\b").matcher(s);
int count = 0;
```

- a long as `find()` returns true, you have a match
- so convert `group(1)` to a double, add to sum and increment the count.

```
while (m.find()) {
    sum+= Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    count++;
}
```

When done, compute the average.

```
System.out.println(sum + " " + count); // just for demo purposes.
if (count > 0) { //just in case
   double avg = sum/count;
   System.out.println("Avg = " + avg);
}
```

prints

```
221.0 3
Avg = 73.66666666666667
```

Check out the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class for more details.

Formatting the final answer may be desirable.  See [System.out.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer is a very useful way to work with data strings that come files or streams. If your data is separated by a specific character (space in this case), StringTokenizer is a easy way to brake a large string into parts & iterate through the data.

Since you don't seem to care about the other 'words' in the line & have not specified if it will be a constant number (middle name?) my example puts all the tokens in an array to get the last three like in the question.  I have also added the parseInt() method to convert from strings to int.  Here is how you would tokenize your lines.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

  List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
  while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    tokens.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
  }

  test3 = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(tokens.size()-1));
  test2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(tokens.size()-2));
  test1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(tokens.size()-3));
}
```